# How to display a popup only when a record is created and not edited?

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am trying to show the user a popup only when the record is created. For every subsequent edit and save, the popup shouldn't be displayed. 
I have created 2 VF pages and 2 controllers so far and now I need some guidance on how to display this popup(QADuplicateAlert) only when a record is newly created.

Since I am passing the Id of my current page/record into the controller, the popup is displaying every time I edit something and save the page. Instead, I want this popup to only appear when the record is created the first time.

Any help is much appreciated!

Main Popup Page
https://gist.github.com/miragedeb/651dadd518cd19aef72c

Controller for the above 
https://gist.github.com/miragedeb/25f3054a7cc304f03ac8

Handling the condition on when to pop up the page
https://gist.github.com/miragedeb/d2a358420118df57ed74

Controller for the above
https://gist.github.com/miragedeb/34aafd27de7360d946e3

Comment: I can't see where you are actually checking whether you should open the popup - where is that code? Essentially, you would probably use a flag field that you'd write to on record creation. If the flag is empty, show the popup, else don't. The flag could be written to in a trigger, in a controller or a workflow/fieldupdate.

Comment: Hey CaspNZ,
I haven't written that code yet. I will try incorporating the flag idea you suggested and get back with the results.

Comment: Is it possible to update the flag 5 seconds after  creating/inserting a new record?

Comment: If you are wanting something so soon after update, then Javascript might be your only option: window.setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds); From there, you could call a remoteobject method on your controller to update the object. Why do you need this? Can you explain the whole flow of object creation and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is what my workflow looks like. 
1. User creates a new record and saves it. 
2. I retrieve this new record's Id and find duplicate records (based on a field value).
3. As soon as the user is done saving, I display a VF popup with a list of all such duplicate tasks, if and only if duplicate records exist. Otherwise no popup is shown.
The  issue is that this VF pop up is appearing whenever the record page is being reloaded or edited and saved. I only want it to appear once when the user creates the record and saves it. After that, the user should never ever see the VF popup on this record.

Comment: I tried implementing the flag logic. I set the flag's default value to be false. I created a field update to set the flag to true as soon as a record is created. Only if the flag's value is true, I will show the VF popup. But the challenge now is to set the flag value back to false moments after the record has been created so that when the user reloads the page (let's say after 1 second or more), the VF popup isn't displayed again. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of a flag, use a timestamp. You could calculate this timestamp value on the fly in the controller (creationdatetime + 5 seconds > now()) or set a field (only on insert) to be five seconds greater than the time you saved the record.

Comment: You can find whether the record is new by using CreatedDate == LastModifiedDate